# Synchronous UITableView/UICollectionView usage for offline data

Tags: ios, uitableview, synchronous

I'm having great fun trying to wrangle the iOS `UITableView/UICollectionView` views to do what I need. Essentially, I have some data which is interacted with locally - no network latency and the manipulations are all trivial enough to be done synchronously.

However, reloading the data in these classes seems to happen asynchronously by default, with no obvious means to use them synchronously. `reloadData()` seems to be only way to force an update without a user interaction like a scroll, but it is async with no obvious sync alternative.

There is a lot of functionality that these classes provide (particularly with drag and drop) but the obvious delay when a user is directly manipulating the data is a bit of a dealbreaker. Experiments with, say, forcing the View's `dataSource` to a different class upon a user changing data defeat the purpose of using these classes and make the situation more complex.

Are there any means to use these classes in a largely synchronous way?

Comment: Unless you are fundamentally changing the entire dataset (such as when switching the `dataSource` as you mention), `reloadData` should be avoided.  You can use `reloadRows`, `insertRows` and `deleteRows` to effect changes in a more granular way.  Perhaps you could clarify your question with a specific example of what you are trying to do and the problem you have with the tableview methods?

Answer (score 0):

Crikey - ask a stupid question after hours of trying and the answer comes 5 mins later.

I realised my error here was not with the TableView updating on time, but on the `dataSource` retaining data when it should have been cleared.

For what I can see - `reloadData` does occur asynchronously, but within a fairly short render cycle which should be imperceptible to a user.

As @Paulw11 noted, the better way to do this is via the row-based manipulations if you are not nuking the data set on each mutation (as I am)